# Gap between readyState complete and onload

Tags: javascript

I am injecting this code into a website. Is there any possibility, that loader.load() won't be executed?

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  loader.load();
} else {
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     loader.load();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there would be a problem with your code (most likely not), but to be consistent i would avoid mixing `document` and `window` .

```js
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  loader.load();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
    if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
      loader.load();
    }
  });
}
```

---

But there is always the possibility that there is another `load` handler attached, before yours, which calls the `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` which would cause all subsequent event handlers to not be called.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event)=>{
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('load 1');
})

window.addEventListener('load', (event)=>{
    console.log('load 2');
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question is more like, is there a time during the injection where none of these ways is true anymore, so that loader.load() will be executed. Like For the first you are to early and for the other you are too late and missed all.

Comment: @Brütüs, yes i understood. To my knowledge, there would be no gap. But my suggestion is using the same property to check, makes it more robust. (*The `readystate === 'complete'` handles the same case as `window.load`*)

Comment: @Brütüs, also added a possibility that your code might not run, which is not due to a gap, but due to another handler stopping the event propagation.